# Tkzinc like library in java

Tags: java, tcl, tk-toolkit

I need to develop some canvas window with graphical entities. 
I want to know is there library similar to **Tkzinc  in java**?

http://www.tkzinc.org/tkzinc/index.php

Comment: Tkzinc does a lot. Which parts do you need? (Please don't say “all of it”…)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've used Eclipse [GEF](http://www.eclipse.org/gef/) before, but that is built on top of an SWT canvas, not Swing. I'm not sure if that's compatible with what you need.

It allows you to build an object-oriented graphical model which responds to events and can be moved around, etc.

The underlying drawing framework is [Draw2D](http://www.eclipse.org/gef/draw2d/index.php) which might be useful on its own if you don't want a full MVC framework for editing a model.